# Solved: CORS issue after deploying a nest js backend api on vercel platform

Tags: node.js, deployment, cors, nestjs, vercel

I have deployed a Nest js backend api on Vercel and it kinda working because I can see the home page after deployment, and I can send a get request to fetch all users for example, But I can't send a POST request to make a login and I get this CORS error in the console
[cors error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUBCj.png)
I'm sure of my cors configurations is correct and that my API is working properly because I have deployed the backend on a different platform and it's working as it should and I don't get this cors error, I also have this vercel.json file:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "name": "tasks-api",
  "buildCommand": "npm start",
  "installCommand": "npm install",
  "regions": ["fra1"],
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "dist/main.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "dist/main.js",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and these some pics of the get request to fetch all users
[GET request: fetching all users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ44I.png)
[GET request: fetching all users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsodr.png)

I think the issue is related to the headers, but I just can't figure out the problem.

EDIT :

I just solved this problem by adding the dist folder to the repo as it turns out that Vercel needs this folder to be already there before deployment because it doesn't actually build your project files like a normal backend server.

Comment: How did you enabled cors?

Comment: Actually I have solved the problem and the api is running fine now

Comment: @Ahmad_Yousif how you solved it?

Comment: you need to add the dist folder in the repo, Vercel needs the folder to be already there, because it doesn't actually build or generate the dist folder.

Comment: @Ahmad_Yousif you are a life saver, I was trying everything, but nothing was working until I pushed the dist/ changes. Thanks a lot!